# Why are the file contents present in the console log but not in the request object?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I cannot understand why the file contents show up successfully in the `console.log(data);` but when I `dd($file);`, it's an empty array (`[]`).

I've tried switching `$request->file('file');` to `$request->get('file');` but same result (one of many different attempts to rectify this).

I've literally tried everything under the sun to rectify this but to no avail.   How can I make it so that `$file` can display what I'm seeing in `console.log(data)` when it comes to `$file`?

**Note:** `name`, `email` and `messageText` show up fine in the request object but for some reason `file`, isn't complying.  I didn't include the JSX for these to reduce the amount of code to look at.

Controller code:

```
$name                        = $request->get('name');
$email                       = $request->get('email');
$file                        = $request->file('file'); 
$messageText                 = $request->get('messageText');

dd($request->all()); // name, email and messageText show up fine. 
dd($file); // returns [] even though console.log() shows its populated
```

frontend code:

```
const [fileName, setFileName]                                                 = useState("");
const [fileChosen, setFileChosen]                                             = useState(false);
const [fileContent, setFileContent]                                           = useState(null);

// Create a reference to the hidden file input element
const hiddenFileInput = React.useRef(null);

const handleClick = () => {
    // Programmatically click the hidden file input element
    // when the Button component is clicked
    hiddenFileInput.current.click();
};

// Call a function (passed as a prop from the parent component to handle the user-selected file
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFileChosen(true);
    setFileContent(event.target.files[0]);
    setFileName(event.target.files[0].name);
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {
        'name' : name,
        'email' : email,
        'file'  : fileContent,
        'messageText' : messageText
    };

    console.log(data);

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json'
    };

    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/support', data, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
        }).catch(error => {
        let errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
        let errorStatus  = error.response.status;

        setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
        setErrorStatus(errorStatus);
    });
};

return(
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data/">
  <div className="contact-form-group">
    <label htmlFor="file"/>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" hidden onChange={handleChange} ref={hiddenFileInput}/>
    <button type="button" id="custom-button" onClick={handleClick}>Choose File</button>
    <span id="custom-text">{!fileChosen ? "No file chosen, yet" : fileName}</span>
  </div>
 </form>
);
```

`console.log(data)` output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please check, is there any typo for the tag.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data/" => enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

I hope this can you help!

Comment: Good catch.  I made the change but still getting the same result :(.